# How to map interactive plot of Geojson polygons using python folium, geopandas and pandas from csv file?

Tags: pandas, openstreetmap, geojson, geopandas, folium

I am trying to achieve an interactive map (in .html file) that shows polygons mapped using this geojson column from this below csv. I would like to incorporate python libraries such as pandas, geopandas and folium. The output should be an html file that allows interaction of the map and when we hover over the polygon--the airport, height, unique_code and  start_date shows up.

Here is sample csv file (I am separating each record by space for easy to read purpose):

```
unique_code,distinct_id,airport,geojson,height,start_date,end_date

ASD12356,2654935,YTZ,"{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[-79.396249,43.629351],[-79.393073,43.627192],[-79.395562,43.624381],[-79.398395,43.626369],[-79.396249,43.629351]]],"type":"Polygon"},"type":"Feature","properties":{"MaxAltitude":"50","StartDateTime":"2023-05-18T11:00:11Z","airspaceClassCodes":["D"],"facility":"YTZ","ignoreMaps":false}}]}",50,5/18/2023 11:00,5/18/2023 13:30

ACF32659,9865321,YYZ,"{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[-79.630513,43.684646],[-79.625399,43.681213],[-79.627544,43.678917],[-79.629433,43.680189],[-79.630513,43.684646]]],"type":"Polygon"},"type":"Feature","properties":{"MaxAltitude":"100","StartDateTime":"2023-05-20T08:00:09Z","airspaceClassCodes":["D"],"facility":"YYZ","ignoreMaps":false}}]}",100,5/20/2023 9:00,5/20/2023 9:30

ABG69543,6452654,YXU,"{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[-81.145449,43.040584],[-81.144214,43.038541],[-81.150006,43.034278],[-81.156126,43.039133],[-81.145449,43.040584]]],"type":"Polygon"},"type":"Feature","properties":{"MaxAltitude":"80","StartDateTime":"2023-05-29T05:00:09Z","airspaceClassCodes":["D"],"facility":"YXU","ignoreMaps":false}}]}",80,5/29/2023 5:00,5/29/2023 7:30
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello @BERA, I was able to put together this up to now. 
" " " 
import sys
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
grid_data = pd.read_csv('sample_mapper_as_csv.csv')
grid_data = pd.DataFrame(grid_data)
feature_list = []
for row in grid_data.itertuples(index=False):
    geojson = grid_data['geojson']
    #loaded_geojson = json.loads(geojson)
    feature = grid_data['geojson'][1]
    print(feature)

*No luck so far with even process of data!  Help Appreciated*

Comment: I have used this code above but could not parse the data that is in geojson as csv format.